# From a group of $10$ boys and $5$ girls, a committee of $6$ students containing at least $2$ girls in chosen at random.

Tags: probability

From a group of $10$ boys and $5$ girls, a committee of $6$ students chosen at random. How many $6$ person committee containing at least $2$ girls possible?

This is my answer: They ask at least $2$ girls. so, $(^5C_2 \cdot $ $^{10}C_4)$ $ + (^5C_3 \cdot $ $^{10}C_3)$ $+ (^5C_4\cdot$ $^{10}C_2)$ $+ (^5C_5 \cdot $ $^{10}C_1) = 3535$

is the answer correct? if wrong mean teach me the way to solve this question.

Comment: are these questions from "probability: a concise course" ?

Comment: i think the hypergeometric distribution is what you want. its like you are drawing from an urn that contains two kinds of balls "The following conditions characterize the hypergeometric distribution:

The result of each draw (the elements of the population being sampled) can be classified into one of two mutually exclusive categories (e.g. Pass/Fail or Female/Male or Employed/Unemployed).
The probability of a success changes on each draw, as each draw decreases the population (sampling without replacement from a finite population)." =wikipedia. hypergeometric distribution

Comment: I think the answer is correct and makes sense.  I don't think hypergeometric distribution is appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you got is correct and so is the method.

If you want another method, you can take all the cases $^{15}C_6$ and subtract from them the cases where $0$ girls are chosen $^5C_0 \cdot$ $^{10}C_6$ and where $1$ girl is chosen $^5C_1 \cdot ^{10}C_5$ which also gives $3535$ as the answer.